# How to use substring with replace in one query?

Tags: mysql, replace, substring

Hi How can I add REPLACE to the following query?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(title,1,1) AS titlealpha,
COUNT(title)
FROM serien
WHERE not_seen =''
GROUP BY titlealpha;
```

From an alphabetical list, with **titlealpha** I try to replace extraordinary letters, like öäüéàè, into normal abc... letters.

```
REPLACE(titlealpha, 'ä', 'a')
REPLACE(titlealpha, 'ö', 'o')
```

Is there also a short, clean way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(title,1,1), 'ä', 'a'), 'ö', 'o') 
AS titlealpha,
COUNT(title)
FROM serien
WHERE not_seen =''
GROUP BY titlealpha;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great! First I thought, it don't. Then I realized the upper and lower case is also important.

Answer (score 1):

a easy way is to replace the this in all rows. MySQL only write the Record if it change

like

```
UPDATE serien set title = replace(title, 'ä' , 'a');
```

or you can put multi replaces in one Statement

```
UPDATE serien set title = REPLACE( REPLACE(title, 'ä' , 'a'), 'Ä', 'A');
```

ans so on

Comment: With your suggestion the database entries get changed. I don't wanna change them, just read out for my special case. Thanks anyway. 
But is it possible to update the AS titlealpha within the query? Or is this not working, because what I'm afraid of, the query needs a hard table, not an alias?